# How to stop jersey client from throwing exception on Http 301?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

I am using the Jersey client to run some integration tests against my service. However, one of my calls sends a redirect. I am expecting to get a redirect but when Jersey Client gets the redirect it errors out with a com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException. Is there some way to make it accept the response with the redirect and just let me know what it got?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: If you set the entity type to ClientResponse rather than String etc you will not get the exception. You can then read the response code and issue a new request yourself. I have not found a way to do this transparently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch UniformInterfaceException which provides response field containing all the details.

You could additionally write some hamcrest matchers to express your expectations:

```
import static javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status.*;
import static org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.*;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

import org.hamcrest.*;
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.*;

public class MyResourceShould {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException unsuccessfulResponse = none();

    private WebResource resource;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Client client = Client.create();
        client.setFollowRedirects(false);
        resource = client.resource("http://example.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void reportMovedPermanently() {
        unsuccessfulResponse.expect(statusCode(MOVED_PERMANENTLY));

        resource.path("redirecting").get(String.class);
    }

    public static Matcher<UniformInterfaceException> statusCode(Status status) {
        return new UniformInterfaceExceptionResponseStatusMatcher(status);
    }

}

class UniformInterfaceExceptionResponseStatusMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<UniformInterfaceException> {

    private final int statusCode;

    public UniformInterfaceExceptionResponseStatusMatcher(Status status) {
        this.statusCode = status.getStatusCode();
    }

    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("response with status ").appendValue(statusCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(UniformInterfaceException exception) {
        return exception.getResponse().getStatus() == statusCode;
    }

}
```

Also note that follow redirects (in setUp method) should be set to false in order to get UniformInterfaceException instead of following redirect (if one is specified in Location header).